# debug node js through task runner explorer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, task-runner-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with npm task runner explorer. Through the task runner I am executing node scripts with the node command. How can I have Visual Studio debugging the invoked Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

From the [nodejstools Advanced-Debugging wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Advanced-Debugging#local-attach)   :

> It is also possible to attach to a locally running Node.exe process,
>   **if** it was started with debugging enabled, using the **'--debug'** command
>   line argument:

So if you are using your VS2017 task runner explorer to run npm tasks with the NPM Task runner extension you'll have to adjust your npm scripts task to something like this :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node --debug .\\cool-script.js"
  },
```

Comment: how to do it (debug) when running Gulpgile.js in Task Runner Explorer?